# Does Facebook have Ads now?

Tags: safari, facebook

Does Facebook have Ads now?

Or does my `Safari` have a virus?

Has anyone experienced a `Twitter` Ad on their `Facebook`?

[image]

Comment: You've previously never seen an Ad on facebook? Facebook must be doing the Ad placements totally wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook functionality and not Apple in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always had ads on Facebook. The content of your ads depends on what websites you recently visited on the Internet. For example, after I searched for some used motherboards, I started seeing ads of motherboard on Facebook.

You may be able to change this by going though your security and advertisement settings on Facebook.

*Edit:* Here's a link to the [Facebook Ads](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=ads) settings page.

Comment: Ohh wow. I didn't know that. Thanks. I will go check on that now.

Comment: @evoque2015 Here's a link to one of the settings pages: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=ads